# Can I change the order of li elements conditionally in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a list with side menu options, some of them are normal categories, some of them are static, here is my code:

```
//const type = the type is either categories or static
{items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <li>
                {type !== 'categories' ? (
                    <> Static </>
                ) : (
                    <> Category </>
                )}
            </li>
        );
    })}
```

So in the items that are of type static I have a variable that comes from the back end which is called display, its value could be either 'top' or 'bottom', what I want to do is, if the type is equal to 'static', to move the order of the li to the value item.display has, for example:

```
<li>----</li> //type static   //item.display: top
<li>++++</li> //type static  //item.display: bottom
<li>""""</li> //type categories //item.display doesn't exist here
<li>::::</li> //type categories //item.display doesn't exist here
```

In the example above the li filled with the symbol '+' has a value of display: bottom,
so it should go to the bottom of the list and the list should now look like that:

```
<li>----</li> //type static   //item.display: top
<li>""""</li> //type categories //item.display doesn't exist here
<li>::::</li> //type categories //item.display doesn't exist here
<li>++++</li> //type static  //item.display: bottom
```

How can I implement that logic, I already tried doing it with inline styles like so:

```
<li style={{order: item.display === "top" ? items.length.toString() : "1"}}>
```

I am not even sure if this is a viable HTML, but it didn't work anyway, what are your suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: if you use a flex or grid ul, order:0 can be used for top and order:1 for bottom example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PoprRxY

Answer (score 1):

You can control the order using `items.sort()` before you map it into virtual dom nodes.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
  let items = [
    { text: '----', type: 'static', display: 'top' },
    { text: '++++', type: 'static', display: 'bottom' },
    { text: '""""', type: 'categories' },
    { text: '::::', type: 'categories' },
  ]
  return (
    <ul>
      {items
        .sort((a, b) =>
          a.display === b.display
            ? 0
            : a.display === 'top'
            ? -1
            : a.display === 'bottom'
            ? 1
            : 0,
        )
        .map(item => (
            <li>
                {item.type !== 'categories' ? (
                    <> Static </>
                ) : (
                    <> Category </>
                )}
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default App
```

output:

```html
<ul>
  <li>----</li>
  <li>""""</li>
  <li>::::</li>
  <li>++++</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be that you have a mapping from string to number and a little helper function

```
const displayMap = {
  top: 0,
  default: 1,
  bottom: 2
};

const compareDisplay(a,b){
  let disp1 = a.display ?? 'default';
  let disp2 = b.display ?? 'default';
  return displayMap[disp1] > displayMap[disp2] ? 1 : -1;
}
```

in case if display is not defined, it will take `default`, which is mapped to the middle value
In case display also contains other values than `top` or `bottom`, you need to add a bit of logic to the helper function

you can use this mapping, to sort your objects before mapping

```
{
  items.sort((a,b) => compareDisplay(a,b)).map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li>
        {
          type !== 'categories' ?
            (<> Static </>) :
            (<> Category </>)
        }
      </li>
    );
})}
```